# Extracting value from string using regex and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string like:

```
</gd:organization><gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='CM@Aart.com'/><gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='da@ammeart.com' primary='true'/><gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'>011 360 51 60</gd:phoneNumber>
```

I need to remove from the string:

```
<gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='CM@Aart.com'/>
```

- based on a match to: `CM@Aart.com`.

It has to be done in basic JavaScript and I can't import any special parsing tools. I can't seem to find a combination that does not error out.

Thank you!

Comment: Nowhere near enough information - you're asking for a general RegEx but provide only one example input/output.  Tell us the characteristics of what it is you need to remove.

Comment: I get these xml strings that contain contact information from Google and need to remove certain elements containing a certain email address.

Comment: Sorry I had not added the full code.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid XML (starts with a close tag), if it was you could use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser). RegExp isn't designed to parse stuff like this.

Comment: If only I could but I need to do it in Google Apps Script which means no DOMParser and there is no built in methods to handle XML. Yes I only posted part of the string.

Comment: @JamesFerreira: You can deal with XML like it's supposed to, you can use third party API's, and AFAIK, Google Apps Script _does_ have its own Xml object: [second example here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/external_apis): SOAP services use XML, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this must be done in RegExp, you could attempt something like the following **only** if you know that all `<gd:email>` parts will have an *address* attribute, quotes are `'` and end `/>` without `address='` or `/>` appearing inside any values on those attributes.

```
"</gd:organization><gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='CM@Aart.com'/><gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='da@ammeart.com' primary='true'/><gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'>011 360 51 60</gd:phoneNumber>"
.replace(
    /<gd:email .*?address='([^']*)'.*?\/>/g, // match email node
    function (a, b) { // replacement logic
        if (b === 'CM@Aart.com') return '';
        return a;
    }
);
```

As I said in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14657201/1615483#comment-20483375), the best way to achieve this would actually be with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) which is a native JavaScript XML parser, but the string you have given us is not valid XML as it begins with a close tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough, do tell if you need any changes:

```
var inputString = "</gd:organization><gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='CM@Aart.com'/><gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='da@ammeart.com' primary='true'/><gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'>011 360 51 60</gd:phoneNumber>";
var outputString = inputString.split("CM@Aart.com")[1].substring(3);
alert(outputString);
```

I've posted a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BssD/) for it.

Comment: I think the email address is an unknown, and it's precisely that piece of info the OP wants to extract...